# Is it possible to make the WebView in a KivyMD application not overlap the interface?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

When the application is launched, the top menu should be displayed, the bottom navigation bar should be present, and in the center of the screen, the web page should be displayed. However, for some reason, the WebView is overlapping the entire application interface and occupying the entire screen space. Here is my code, and at the bottom, there is a Wv class that should display Google within the application upon launch

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import CommonElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigation, MDBottomNavigationItem
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from jnius import autoclass
from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

WebView = autoclass('android.webkit.WebView')
WebViewClient = autoclass('android.webkit.WebViewClient')
activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity').mActivity

class KeyPay(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"
        return Builder.load_string('''
<DrawerClickableItem@MDNavigationDrawerItem>
    focus_color: "#d3d3d3"
    text_color: "#4a4939"
    icon_color: "#000000"
    ripple_color: "#808080"
    selected_color: "#006400"
MDScreenManager:
    id: MyScreenManager
    MDScreen:
        name: 'main_screen'
        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDTopAppBar:
                            title: "KEY-PAY"
                            elevation: 4
                            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                            md_bg_color: "#ffffff"
                            specific_text_color: "#000000"
                            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                                
                        Wv:
                            id: Mywebview
                            
                        MDBottomNavigation:
                            selected_color_background: "green"
                            text_color_active: "lightgrey"
                            text_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
                            icon_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
                            text_color_normal: 0, 0, 0, 1
                            icon_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
                            text_color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1
                            icon_color_active: 0, 0, 0, 1
                            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                                name: 'screen 1'
                                text: 'Главная'
                                icon: 'home-roof'
                                badge_icon: ""

''')
    
class Wv(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Wv, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(create_webview, 0)
        
@run_on_ui_thread
def create_webview(self, *args):
    webview = WebView(activity)
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(True)
    wvc = WebViewClient()
    webview.setWebViewClient(wvc)
    activity.setContentView(webview)
    webview.loadUrl('http://www.google.com')
    
class ExtendedButton(MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, CommonElevationBehavior):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.padding = "16dp"
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_spacing)
        
    def set_spacing(self, interval):
        self.ids.box.spacing = "12dp"
        
    def set_radius(self, *args):
        if self.rounded_button:
            self._radius = self.radius = self.height / 4
            
KeyPay().run()
```

I tried creating another BoxLayout, placing it inside the existing BoxLayout, and specifying its dimensions, but the situation did not change. The WebView still opens in full screen.

```
        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        MDTopAppBar:
                            title: "KEY-PAY"
                            elevation: 4
                            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
                            md_bg_color: "#ffffff"
                            specific_text_color: "#000000"
                            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        
                        BoxLayout:
                            orientation: 'vertical'
                            size_hint: (0.8, 0.5)
                            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}                                                       
                        
                            Wv:
                                id: Mywebview
```